'Access to fetch has been blocked by CORS policy' Error while trying to send GET request using chrome extension
let link = https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?                   key=XXXXXXXXXX&steamids=764564564575656
fetch(link)
    .then(resp => {
        resp.json()
    })
    .then(data=> {
        console.log(data)
})

I am trying to develop chrome extension that gets data from specific website and sends get request to an API, I have this problem when I try to send GET request to that API website I get this error. It looks like that website blocks any external requests using extension, is there any possible way to avoid this?
I get this error:
from origin 'https://csfloat.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

You have to adapt your manifest file for a valid host_permissios property, so that it contains the websites you want to access.

this is because you are trying to access api.steampowered.com from different origin https://csfloat.com, you need to tell your server to allow it to access the server resources, if you are using NodeJS for backend, install cors (Cross-origin resource sharing) through npm install cors and then in your server code :
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors({ origin: "https://csfloat.com/" }));


this way your server can be accessed and only can be accessed from https://csfloat.com

that makes little sense. the request is being issued by a chrome extension.

@muzzletov sry didn't notice that, but i think its the same thing, cors error happens when the origin requesting the resource is of a different origin and doesn't have access to the resource because the resource didn't allow it to access it

thats okay that you do, but youre wrong

Do you really think that the OP has access to the Steam server code?

You get downvotes because the answer is wrong and not helpful. Please stop cursing and offending other users.
